# Array of usernames as parameter in GET Request - nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express, arraylist

I need to  send an array of user names in GET request as parameters, say

```
/show_user/?uname=user1&uname=user2&uname=user3&uname=user4
```

and then inside the express server.js file can I retrieve it as:

```
var username = req.query.uname;  //['user1', 'user2','user3','user4']
```

Will this work?

Comment: It works as u mentioned, unless you have a validation for the uname as string, if there is no validation for the field you will get an array of usernames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Just send the attribute as your are doing and on the express side you can pull it out as

```
var username = req.query.uname;  //['user1', 'user2','user3','user4']
```

Answer (score 4):

a possible solution is to send a GET request with only one parameter

```
/show_user/?uname=user1;user2;user3
```

And split the string using a specified operator like ';'

```
var usernames = JSON.parse(req.params.uname).split(";")
```

A second solution is to send a POST with a `application/json`

```
{
   uname: ['user1','user2','user3'],
}
```

And get the object; maybe you need to add the body-parser middleware

```
var usernames = JSON.parse(req.body.uname);
```

Comment: You can't use `&` as mentioned above, `&` operator will divide query into multiple query fields, its better to use comma separated strings

Answer (score 2):

My solution with GET

REST Call for two Users

`/user/?names=Peter;Bob`

Express Code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/user/', (req, res) => {
  const names = req.query.names.split(';');
  console.log(names);
  res.send({ text: 'Hello World' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The names get stored in an array like this:
`[ 'Peter', 'Bob' ]`

Answer (score 0):

In express, use this to get the query parameter:

```js
app.get('/show_user', (req, res) => {
  const names = req.query.uname || []
  console.log('/show_user', names)
  res.json(names)
})
```

Be careful, this url will not create an array in express

```
/show_user/?uname=user1
```

Add `[]` to the param name to ensure the server treats the param as an array. E.g.

```
/show_user/?uname[]=user1
```

It seems redundant, but there may be cases where you have only one item to send.